# Drool 5.3.3.Final to Drool 6.0.0.Final Migration. RuleAgent alternate in Drool 6

Tags: drools

I am new to drool and question might be quite easy but headache for a now

what is the alternate to org.drools.agent.RuleAgent in drools 6.0.0 or how can i create newInstance of RuleAgent using drool 6.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DroolsAgent` class was removed from version 6 and greater. You can achieve a similar behavior (and probably event more) with the `KieScanner` or with `KieContainer.updateToVersion()`.

Both ways are kind of documented in the oficial documentation.

- KieScanner: http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.0.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#_kiescanner
- KieContainer.updateToVersion(): http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.0.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#_kiescanner

Hope it helps,

Comment: RuleAgent agent = org.drools.agent.RuleAgent.newRuleAgent(properties);  how can i acive same thing using KieScanner

Comment: Read the documentation and check-out the tests they have. For example: https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/blob/master/kie-ci/src/test/java/org/kie/scanner/KieScannerIncrementalCompilationTest.java